# Send to the Google Play and come back from there got black screen?

Tags: cocos2d-android

I have a CCScene, In the CCScene there is button "More Apps / rate App".

When I tapped on, It'll take me to the play store and when I press the back button I got the black screen

but What is open that time "CCScene which have the button "More Apps /Rate app" ".

Anybody suggest what is the matter ??

Answer (score 0):

I think your screen orientation may be changing when you moving from that activity so that it killing that scene,So place this line in your activity of manifest file and try

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Comment: check by placing your moving to play store code in runOnUiThread()

Comment: no change .... I create a new dummy and copy_paste the code and it run perfectly. I added some function on it .. occuring the same problem

Comment: does we can get the back button event when we come back to the google play

Comment: no its not possible to get Google play event when you pressed back.Does your app saving the instance when you clicking home and lock button